# Meaning of "Get to"

Tags: word-meaning

Please clarify the exact meaning of "get to" in the quote below.

> All good-hearted souls **get to** pass through

There is a bubble shield approaching  them that he is afraid he would not be able to pass through it so he ask the good witch about it and she says that in answer to him.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of

> All good-hearted souls get to pass through

is

> All good-hearted souls **are allowed to** pass through

See sense 14 at Wiktionary's page for the verb *[get](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get#Verb)*:

> (intransitive, followed by infinitive) To be able, permitted (to do
> something); to have the opportunity (to do something).
>
> I'm so jealous that you **got** to see them perform live!
>
> The finders **get** to keep 80  percent of the treasure.

The *to* here is part of the infinitive form of the verb *to pass*.

Answer (score 6):

I am expanding on the answer provided by CopperKettle, well as CopperKEttle mentioned,

**get to** can mean **allowed to**

there is another way you can look at it, Let me try to explain it with a few examples

1) If you win the lucky draw, you get to go on a cruise to Hawaii
2) If you join our group, you get to enjoy the weekend in a cabin by the lake.
3) You get to eat dinner only after you finish the homework
4) You get to vote once you turn 18

In sentences 1) and 2) **get to** means that you have been "provided with an opportunity", in sentences 3) and 4) **get to** means you are "allowed to".

So in the sentence under question "All good-hearted souls get to pass through"

get to can mean

1) All good-hearted souls are **allowed to** (get to) pass through - in this context, you want to do something and you are given permission to do that

2) All good-hearted souls get the opportunity to (get to) pass through - in this context, you are presented with the opportunity, you can decide to take it or leave it.

So next time when you come across "get to", well you get to decide what it means.

Comment: All who expand on my answers get my respect, Nandagopal! (0: Just a little cavil: I believe only the word 'get' should be highlighted, because 'to' is part of the verb following it. Like in the sentence "all good kids get a present on Christmas" we would highlight 'get', not 'get a' or 'get on', lest the learner be confused. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle Got it, you are spot on.

Comment: @CopperKettle Thank you very much. I was going to ask the same thing. Thank you NANDAGOPAL for the details.

Comment: `You are get to vote once you turn 18` - this doesn't feel like proper English; the `are` should not be there!

Comment: @ANeves cheers mate, sorry, i forgot to edit it out, It is a mistake and I will correct it at once, but it was unintentional, typed it in a hurry, embarrassing mistake though.

Comment: Thank you NANDANGOPAL.  I knew it must be a substitute for "have to" , "able to" or "allowed to" but i didn't know exactly which one is the right choice. I chose CK's answer because i thought it would be easier for learners to understand in future and yours would be very nice to read for details, if they are interested. Thank you very much again for your instructive answer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between [“get to”](http://paws4udogs.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/get-to-vs-have-to/) and “have to” tasks all has to do with motivation. “Get to” tasks are reinforcing in and of themselves. They’re enjoyable, which is why we look forward to them. “Have to” tasks, on the other hand, are reinforcing only in the sense of relief we feel when they’re done. Finishing a “have to” task feels good, because there’s a sense of completeness. Until the “have to” task has been finished, it looms over our head.

Comment: This is generally true. "get to" = "allowed to" which means permission. Sometimes we feel obligated to ask for permission to do or have things we desire.  **But often they can be used in the opposite** for toughness ("Private! You get to clean the latrines!") for sarcasm ("Yay. I get to wash all these dishes while you guys go have fun.") or humor (Father playing with son: "Now Johnny, you **have to** eat this cake. I know you don't want to.")  Also, "have to" can indicate an extreme desire, as if it was to the point of obligation: "I just **have to** buy this dress... it's so darling!"